# I am trying to validate my shopping list with this code a "..." spread but got a return value of "milk," and just the first value

Tags: javascript

can someone point me what am I missing...
code is below:

```
function validateList(items) {
    if(items.indexOf('veggies') < 0) {
    return ['veggies', ...items]
  }
  return items;
}

validateList('apple', 'fish', 'eggs');
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: You probably mean `function validateList(...items)`. There’s no `milk` in your snippet.

Comment: yes, that was it.. just got dizzy after hours of looking at my screen today.. thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, you are looking for this (using [`spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)):

```js
function validateList(...items) {
    if(items.indexOf('veggies') < 0) {
    return ['veggies', ...items]
  }
  return items;
}

console.log(validateList('apple', 'fish', 'eggs'));
```

Comment: my bad.. dumb.. i forgot the spread in the validateList(...items).. i knew I forgot something.. i just got dizzy looking at my code.. thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling the function you are passing 3 arguments, however, the function expects only 1 argument. It seems you want to represent them into an array. Hence, you will need to update your function to following by using [Rest Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

```js
function validateList(...items) {
    if(items.indexOf('veggies') < 0) {
    return ['veggies', ...items]
  }
  return items;
}

console.log(validateList('apple', 'fish', 'eggs'));
```